# customize tableview background using tableView willDisplayCell: delegate method

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, uiimage

I want to customize tableview background with my own images i am using the fallowing code to customize cell background view

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
    UIImage *background = nil;

    if (rowIndex == 0) {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableTopBackground.png"];
    } else if (rowIndex == rowCount - 1) {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableBottomBackground.png"];
    } else {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableMiddleBackground.png"];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:background]];

}
```

my problem is the bottom cell images and middle cell images are interchanged when i run in ios5 (image 1) but in ios6 it was fine(image 2).

[image: ios 5 image]

[image: ios 6 image]

but setting the background color it was working fine in both ios5 and ios 6. can any one help me in solving it.

writing the code in cellForRowatindexpath its working but why does it not working in willdisplaycell.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `image`  in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and add with

```
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

This code write between

```
if(cell == nil)
 {
 }
```

Comment: ya when i wrote the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath it was working fine.

Comment: i want know what is the problem with willdisplaycell

Comment: @Gup.. you set image on cell when cell is  display in process not displayed may be so this will create issue ...BTW your problem is solved or not ???